# Custom Directive multiple times on same page requiring same data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that is going to be on the same page in 2 different locations using 2 different data sets but all the data comes back with one service call.  How can I make the API call once and use the data in both instances of the directive?

Comment: Please provide basic code outline. you are asking people to wire up 3 different components and haven't provided a single byte of code ... that's just not right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a promise from the service after it's called the first time. So both of the directives might call `service.getData().then(directiveCallback)` but the service only fetches the data once from the server. In the service, something like:

```
var serverRequestPending = false;
var dataAlreadyRetrieved = false;
var dataPromise;

this.getData = function() {
   return getDataFromServer();
}

function getDataFromServer() {
    // don't do re-work
    if (dataAlreadyRetrieved || serverRequestPending) {
        return dataPromise;
    }


    serverRequestPending = true;

    dataPromise = apiCallHere(); // your custom API behavior that should return a promise and will resolve with the data
    dataPromise.then(onDataGetComplete);

    return dataPromise;
}

function onDataGetComplete() {
    dataAlreadyRetrieved = true;
    serverRequestPending = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in any case this should always be handled by a service, which one to use and how to handle it, depends on your application,
2 ways using services are

```
1- (my favorite) use your service to get the data from the server and use $cacheFactory to cache the response and serve it to the rest of the directives
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache. 
i like this one better because it abstracts your directive and service from the maintaining the data.

```
2- keep the data in a service local variable and check for existence before making the http call to the server. This solution is not bad but then you'll jave to implement a data cache handler to manage how long should your data live in the service.
```

other solution my least favorite is to implement something similar to #2 but use $rootScope instead and injected everywhere where you want to make your data accessible. this is not my recommendation, but would also work